# SOQL query to retrieve Quote Line Item records from Quote Record

Tags: soql, query, standard-objects, quote, quotelineitem

How would I retrieve all `QuoteLineItem` records from a `Quote` record?

Comment: While it doesn't seem unreasonable to close this question for lack of research, surely `Too Broad` is not the right reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a parent query , you can use a child sub-query, formally known as a [`Left Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Outer_Join):

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM QuoteLineItems) FROM Quote WHERE ...
```

As a separate query:

```
SELECT Id FROM QuoteLineItem WHERE QuoteId = :parent.Id
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the syntax from Parent to Child:-

```
SELECT Id [Fields...,] ,
    ( SELECT Name, [..Fields,] FROM QuoteLineItems )
    FROM Quote
    WHERE Id=:Quote_ID
```

Child Relationship name of Quote Line Item is: `QuoteLineItems`